# Playstation 4 Broken HDMI Port Repair. How to fix this PS4?

Tags: ps4, hdmi

Seems that my HDMI port is broken on my PS4 due to having it plugged in and out all the time. Is there a way to fix this easily? I tried calling sony and they said I'm out of warranty and that it was due to physical damage and they would not take it in. Looking for other options if possible as this was a $500 system!

Comment: When Sony said they wouldn't take it in, didn't they just mean that repairs are going to cost something? It's possible the repair costs are going to be lower than the costs of buying a new PS4. Also, how damaged is the HDMI port? If you're lucky, you might be able to "fix" it yourself by bending the port with a knife or something. Just try and be more careful with cables and ports from now on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a write up of the repair process for the ps4 hdmi port:

> Now as for the PS4 HDMI repair process, it was definitely a much
>   trickier fix than doing a ps3 hdmi port. The PS3 systems has all of
>   the pins and legs being held down on one side of the board. As for the
>   PS4, you had the pins of the HDMI connector on one side and the legs
>   held down on the other side. It wouldn't have been possible to heat
>   just one side and pull off the PS4 HDMI component as the PCB board
>   itself was absorbing all of the heat from one side. Below are some of
>   the repair methods you might see people do:
>
> Use 2 heat guns, but you'll need 3 hands. Also you'd have to becareful
>   of not melting off other small chips around it. Wouldn't recommend
>   doing this, as its mostly for those on a super tight budget and
>   resorting to primitive tools. Yes, a heat gun repair is a primitive
>   repair tool. Hot Air Station is another repair method, but that too is
>   also still tricky as all the heat is generated on one side of the PS4
>   board only. Removing pins from the board first with an exacto knife.
>   Then use a hot air station to remove the PS4 HDMI legs.

http://www.phonerepair.us/blog/ps4-repair-analysis-playstation-4-hdmi-replacement

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the facilities to use a heat gun, (and who outside industry would have) then to be honest you are simply knackered if you don't have warranty.

Mine broke weeks after first release and when I phoned them they sent me a free post box to have it sent to them, after a day or two I got a message back to say it was beyond repair so they would send out a refurbished model (which I assume was repaired for a different fault). Got the refurbished model about a week after I had sent my PS4 off, still works like a treat to this very day, touch wood.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the HDMI port on the PS4 is quite a bit different from the previous consoles; thus making the repair a little more difficult without the proper tools.

We do NOT recommend using a basic "heat-gun" as it will cause more damage than good. Not sure about the exacto knife process either, as it has potential for a bad outcome if you do not have a steady hand while cutting the metal pins; but if you are lacking the tools, then it's a viable option.

The best way to replace the port is with a hot-air rework station, an ultra fine point soldering iron, and a high-powered microscope.

Here are the steps:

1. Remove the motherboard from the case, and clean the old thermal paste.
2. Apply flux to the existing port connections, then begin heating the posts and pins evenly with the rework station.
3. Once the existing solder has reached its melting point, use tweezers to SLOWLY remove the old port.
4. Now clean the board, and inspect for any damaged traces (depending on the severity of the port damage)
5. Now position the new port in place, add solder to the posts to hold it in place, apply flux to the pins, and then individually solder each pin to the motherboard.

Providing you followed the steps, the unit will boot like normal once you re-assemble.